# Simple mathematical puzzle

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

**Puzzle:** $$\begin{array}{}\boxed{3\;\,}&\boxed{150\;\;\;\,}&\boxed{12\;\;\;\,}\\\boxed{7\;\,}&\boxed{3164\;\,}&\boxed{56\;\;\;\,}\\\boxed{16}&\boxed{74112}&\boxed{272\;\;}\\\boxed{32}&\boxed{\text{?}\;\;\;\;\;\;\,}&\boxed{1024\,}\end{array}$$

We have to figure out the question mark.

**My effort:**

I have tried almost for half-an-hour, but can't seem to work out the rule being followed here. I tried
$$\begin{align}
7 - 3 &= 2^2\\  
16 - 7 &= 3^2\\  
32 - 16 &= 4^2
\end{align}$$

This was the only sequence I could figure out but it only works for the first column.

I need help figuring this out, along with a suitable explanation of the answer.

***Note***: This is *not* a homework question.

Comment: From the looks of it, I would think that the first and last column are given and you derive the center column from the outside two.

Comment: Interesting the left to the right appears to be in order 3*(3+1), 7*(7+1), 16*(16+1), then suddenly 32*32...

Comment: @Goinghamateur Or if you look at it a different way, the ratios of 3rd/1st go 4, 8, 17, 32...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer:

> $\mathbf{1049088}$
>  
>  The pattern I noticed was
>  $\text{middle column} = \text{right column}^2 + (\text{left column}\times 2^\text{row number})$
>
>  $2^1\times 3 + 12^2 = 6 + 144  = 150$
>  $2^2\times 7 + 56^2 = 28 + 3136 = 3164$
>  $2^3\times 16 + 272^2 = 128 + 73984 = 74112$
>  $2^4\times 32 + 1024^2 = 512 + 1048576 = 1049088$

My inspiration:

> I divided 74112 by 272 and it came close to 272, so I though of squaring. Then I took the difference and said hey that looks like a multiple of 16, it was, I then applied the algorithm on all of them and the multiple trend of the difference from the square remained, and the 2, 4 ,8 pattern appeared. Leaving the assumption 16 would be the next difference multiplier.